# How can I use Json.NET to deserialise exchange rates from responses from fixer.io?

Tags: c#, json.net, fixer.io

I am writing an app that stores currency rates and I am unsure how to use Json.NET to deserialise the response from [fixer.io](https://fixer.io).

An example response is:

```
{ 
   "success":true,
   "timestamp":1570122547,
   "base":"EUR",
   "date":"2019-10-03",
   "rates":{ 
      "USD":1.098479,
      "EUR":1,
      "ZAR":16.631028,
      "CAD":1.464228
   }
}
```

**Note:** The rates in the response can vary.

> How can I deserialise `rates`? A `Rate` is made up of a Name (string) and Rate (decimal) but I am unsure how to do this

I tried using the "Paste as JSON classes" function in Visual Studio using the above response which resulted a Rates object as below but that is tied to the specific rates - I need it to be able to handle **different** rates

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, decimal>` in place of a fixed class

Comment: See the linked duplicate for an example if you need it.